SpeechSynthesis.speak doesn't start without user interaction
has anyone solved the problem of how to start audio play without user interaction using speechSynthesis.speak? (Firefox 124.0.1 (64 bit) seems to work fine, on Chrome 123.0.6312.59 (64 bit) doesn't work).
This works fine on Firefox but not in Chrome:
window.speechSynthesis.speak(Object.assign(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hallo Bob'), {
  voice: window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(v => v.lang === 'de-DE' && v.name == "Anna")
}))

Thanks.

UPDATE
I was trying this solution, but still nothing (the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'.)
function speakWithoutInteraction(text) { 
    // create an audio context
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext; 
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext(); 
    // create a variable for the synth
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;   
    // Create a SpeechSynthesisUtterance object for the text
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);       
    // get the voice to use (for example the first available)
    const voices = synth.getVoices(); 
    utterance.voice = voices[0];        
    // converts text to audio
    const audioData = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text); 
    synth.speak(audioData); 
    // redirects the audio to the destination of the audio context
    const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioData); 
    // connect to the audio context destination
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination); 
    // run after a short delay
    setTimeout(() => { audioData.onend = () => { 
        audioCtx.close(); // close the audio context after playback ends
        }; 
    }, 1000); // 1 sec
} 
speakWithoutInteraction("Yes! I'm talking without user interaction"); 


Its no longer allowed, but there may be a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265423/javascript-speechsynthesis-speak-without-user-activation-is-no-longer-allowed

Unfortunately, forcing an interaction doesn't seem to work.
Also using a delay, like: setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById('btn_speech').click();
}, 1000); // 1 sec delay ).
What is the best way to simulate a user click?

Simulating a click wont be the same as a human click

const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext; ... will be boolean true or false wouldn't it? .... In regards to "parameter 1 is not of type HTMLMediaElement"
